# Why these x,y coords work in fillRect

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

After being interested in [this code golf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85141/draw-the-national-flag-of-iceland), I decided to just quickly throw a javascript solution together, not trying to golf it. The challenge is to create the Icelandic flag and proportions are defined within the question.

The flag must be 25:18 ratio, so I created a flag of 250x180px size. The white horizontal stripe should then start at 7 units from the top. (1 unit = 10px) So I would assume that this would mean 70px from the top. However in creating the code, I had to change the x,y coords as it didn't look right.

The code is below, can anyone explain why instead of 70px and 80px (for white and red stripes respectively) I had to use 55px and 65px? I must be something straight forward, but I'm confused.

```
<canvas id="i"></canvas>
<script>
    var c=document.getElementById("i").getContext("2d");
    c.fillStyle="#0048e0";
    c.fillRect(0,0,250,180);
    c.fillStyle="white";
    c.fillRect(0,55,250,40);
    c.fillRect(55,0,40,180);
    c.fillStyle="#d72828";
    c.fillRect(0,65,250,20);
    c.fillRect(65,0,20,180);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't set sizes (width and height) of the [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) element. So they are set to default values which are `300` and `150` respectively. Therefore your flag rectangle is clipped to `(280, 150)` rectangle. Due to this clipping white and red stripes look wrong, although actually they are rendered correctly.

So you have to set `width` and `height` of the canvas explicitly by assigning respective attributes of DOM element:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("i");
canvas.width = 250;
canvas.height = 180;
var c=canvas.getContext("2d");
c.fillStyle="#0048e0";
c.fillRect(0,0,250,180);
c.fillStyle="white";
c.fillRect(0,70,250,40);
c.fillRect(70,0,40,180);
c.fillStyle="#d72828";
c.fillRect(0,80,250,20);
c.fillRect(80,0,20,180);
```

Comment: Same idea, up for you :D